# Python random out of range

Tags: python

I am writing a code in Python 3.3.3 that makes a list of 32 teams if you enter say 12 and makes sure that the team that is repeated the most is only repeated once more than that which is being repeated the least. If have done this:

```
import random
if run == '1':
    teams =[]
    randoms = []
    team = 0
    amount = 1
    while team != "done":
        team = input("Please enter team name " + str(amount) +" or enter 'done' if you have finished.\n")
        if team != "done":
            teams.append(team)
            randoms.append(team)
            amount = amount + 1
    length = len(teams)
    while len(teams) != 32:
        if len(teams) < 32-length:
            for x in range (0,length):
                teams.append(teams[x])
        else:
            number = random.randint(0,len(randoms))
            name = randoms[number]
            teams.append(name)
            randoms.remove(name)
        teams.sort()
    for x in range(0,len(teams)):
        print (teams[x])
```

I run the program and enter 12 teams then done. It comes up with the following message:

```
line 29, in <module>
    name = randoms[number]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know this means the number is not in the range of the array's length, but how do I fix this?
Thanks for the feedback. I now have:

```
    import random
    teams =[]
    randoms = []
    team = 0
    amount = 1
    while team != "done":
        team = input("Please enter team name " + str(amount) +" or enter 'done' if you have finished.\n")
        if team != "done":
            teams.append(team)
            randoms.append(team)
            amount = amount + 1
    length = len(teams)
    times =0
    while len(teams) != 32:
        while len(teams) <= 32-length:
            for x in range (0,length+1):
                teamname = teams[x]
                teams.append(teamname)
        else:
           choice = random.choice(randoms)
           teams.append(choice)
           randoms.remove(choice)
        teams.sort()
    for x in range(0,len(teams)):
        print (teams[x])
```

However this returns the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 248, in choice
i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 224, in _randbelow
r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:(File)", line 30, in <module>
choice = random.choice(randoms)
File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 250, in choice
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Switch `randint` to `randrange` - `randint(a, b)` **includes `b`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that there is a special function for ramdonly choosing an element from a list:

```
random.choice(randoms)
```

…should do what you are intending.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint(a, b)` returns random integers between *a* and *b* **inclusive**. Here, `randoms[len(randoms)]` is giving an error. Try `random.randrange` or `random.choice` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
name = randoms[number - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) takes as arguments the *inclusive* bounds for the range. So if your lower bound is 0 you probably want to set the upper bound to `len(randoms)-1`.